# Tab in Image with hotspots

Tags: c#, drawing

I have a problem which I don't know a work around for.
I'm creating a program for the company I work. The program has to write down a deliverypage for sendings we transport because right now the company has over 100 excel files, for every delivery one.

What I got now is a picturebox with an Image and that image has 16 hotspots.
with hotspots I mean Rectangles(Bounds) to know which part on the image the user has clicked on because that part needs to be selected. so far no problem. but my only problem is when hitting the Tab button.

How can I switch from Rectangle to rectangle on the image to the other Rectangle when hitting the tab button. because because there is no tabstop on a rectangle bound.

I already tried adding custom controls using tabstop and that worked great but then I had this problem that the data that has to be written in the content is limited to the area. so I need to paint it directly on the image so using controls is no option for me.

Hope my description is clear enough and else feel free to ask.

Comment: You can fake it, I imagine you can draw a rectangle on screen but just override a keypress for tab that will increase the index of an integer variable that relates to a list of some sort

Comment: This could actually work. Really didn't think of that. I may try that. Thx for the idea. Sometimes you look for something really complicated when its just as easy as that

Comment: No worries :) I won't make it an answer for you for a while because I imagine someone may have an actual solution but I've used this method in the past.

Comment: ok, I tried what you said but it doesn't work.
Somehow Tab doesn't trigger keypress or keydown event. even when I make sure that control is focused it doesn't trigger. It do trigger on normal keys like a-z

More ideas are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Managed to solve my own problem with underlaying code

```
protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
        {
            int selectionIndex = pBoundsCollection.IndexOf(pSelection);
            if (keyData == Keys.Tab)
            {
                while (selectionIndex++ <= pBoundsCollection.Count)
                {
                    if (selectionIndex >= pBoundsCollection.Count)
                    {
                        selectionIndex = 0;
                        pSelection = (CMRField)pBoundsCollection[selectionIndex];
                        Refresh();
                        break;
                    }
                    if (((CMRField)pBoundsCollection[selectionIndex]).IsSelectable)
                    {
                        pSelection = (CMRField)pBoundsCollection[selectionIndex];
                        Refresh();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
        }
```